# Magento 2.3.3 - “the shipping information was unable to be saved” comes for the customers on checkout

Tags: magento2

This problem when I add address first at **http://mywebsite.com/customer/address/**. But when I add an address when checkout dont have a problem. So in debug.log have error

`[2021-04-27 04:00:55] main.CRITICAL: Invalid customer address id 771 {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\NoSuchEntityException(code: 0): Invalid customer address id 771 at /var/www/html/mywebsite/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteAddressValidator.php:79)"} []`

How to fix its?

Comment: I can give you few steps to look into, Check existing address which is throwing error, there would be some invalid info like, Country, state etc..

Comment: Please share some code also at line number 79